# Unable to use PCP Vector with variable target host in Grafana

Tags: vector, grafana

I have a number of servers where PCP Vector is running with standard settings and I want to have some metrics from these servers plotted on graphs in Grafana. I followed the [quickstart guide](https://grafana-pcp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) and was able to query metrics properly from PCP Vector data source with a predefined target host. However I would prefer to have one data source and use a dashboard variable for the target hostname, so I can monitor any host I want from one dashboard using the same data source as it is described [here](https://grafana-pcp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/multiple-vector-hosts.html). I followed the instructions for multiple vector hosts, but it did not work. I tried:

- server mode, browser mode;
- blank URL in the data source, then an override value in the graph settings with the `$host` variable or with the actual hostname typed it;
- URL set in the data source, tested positively, then overridden in the graph settings;
- URLs with and without the trailing slash.

In every case I was getting `Network error` and no data on the graph. I am not sure if the problem is with Grafana or the Vector plugin.

I am using:

- Grafana v7.0.0 (aee1438ff2)
- PCP Vector plugin v2.0.2
- PCP webapp on the target host installed from the package `pcp-webapp-vector-4.1.0-5.el7_6.noarch`

Please post comments if you need more debug information.

Comment: I built the grafana-pcp plugin from source from the master branch and it did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be [a known issue](https://github.com/performancecopilot/grafana-pcp/issues/23): when the PCP Vector data source is set to work in the Browser mode the client web browser communicates with the target host directly. Web browsers use [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) to verify the origin and expect certain HTTP headers in response. It was addressed in [this commit](https://github.com/performancecopilot/pcp/commit/df2426ac8a815e8784a5159d1e633eef6816aaf4) to the PCP plugin code.

The solution is either:

1. to upgrade PCP to v. 5+ on the target hosts and enjoy Grafana v. 7+;
2. to downgrade Grafana to v. 6.6.2 or older and keep using PCP v. 4.X on the target hosts.

Re. #2: The PCP Vector plugin does not work with every web browser, ie. it did not work for me in MS Edge, but did work fine in Firefox.